# Kivy carousel with more than one visible child

Tags: python-3.x, carousel, kivy

I need to create a carousel in the Kivy similar to the following image. 
Kivy carousel displays only one child at a time. How can I also show the previous and next child?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

i think you can create a custom ScrollView to make that work with a boxlayout or grid by adding some properties like spacing and padding to it and allowing the do_scroll_x property to be set to True and and size_hint_x to a number that can allow scrolling...